# Spresense GNSSとAudioを初期化するとエラーが発生する

Tags: spresense

Spresense＋LTE拡張ボード＋加速センサーの構成に、LEDとスピーカーを接続しているのですが、
GPS（GNSS）とAudioを利用すべく、初期化を行なった際にエラーが発生して初期化ができませんでした。

いろいろな組み合わせを試したところ、GPSとAudioを一緒に初期化すると、エラーが出ました。
GPSとAudioを同時に使いたいのですが、対処方法はありますでしょうか。

検証用に作ったコードは以下の通りです。
この内容だと、Audioの初期化でエラーが発生して、初期化ができませんでした。

```
#include <GNSS.h>
#include <Audio.h>
SpGnss Gnss;
AudioClass *myAudio;
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  while(!Serial);
  if (Gnss.begin()) {
    puts("Gnss begin error");
  } else {
    Gnss.select(GPS);
    Gnss.select(QZ_L1CA);
    Gnss.select(QZ_L1S);
    if (Gnss.start(COLD_START)) {
      puts("Gnss start error");
    } else {
      puts("Gnss setup done");
    }
  }
  myAudio = AudioClass::getInstance();
  myAudio->begin();
}
void loop() {
}
```

Answer (score 1):

今回リリースされた、v2.1.0

https://github.com/sonydevworld/spresense-arduino-compatible/releases/tag/v2.1.0

の中に、

[GNSS/Audio] GNSSとAudioの同時動作中にAudioからエラーが発生する可能性がある問題を修正しました。

とありますので、最新版では改善されたようですね。